# I can't install any apps from the Software Center

Tags: software-center, debian

I'm using crouton and running the chroot on a chromebook, when I try to install something I get this message,
(org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.81'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have not this message error but by the way:

- Do you have access to a console?
- Could you install synaptic package manager?
- Then install apps from synaptic?
- Do you tried installing some app from apt-get like

  apt-get install application_you_want

I hope someone of this can give you some idea